# How to add number of items to list view in a new activity(Activity a) accoring to user's selection selection(multiple buttons, inside activity a)?

Tags: java, android, listview

i have defined some buttons(in activity a) using text views and whenever any button will be clicked it'll open an activity(activity b) where i have placed a listview. What i want is to load some list inside my list view according to the button i am pressing in activity a. like for button a i want list view to load 4 items like item1, item2, item3, item4 and for button b i want list view to load 5 items like itemV, itemW, itemX, item4, itemZ.

This is My Activity a

```js
public class ProfileActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements View.OnClickListener {

    private TextView a, b;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_profile);

        a = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.a);
        b = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.b);

        a.setOnClickListener(this);
        b.setOnClickListener(this);
    }

@Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        switch (v.getId()){
           case R.id.a:
                Intent sub1 = new Intent(this, SubCategory.class);
                this.startActivity(sub1);
                break;
            case R.id.b:
                Intent sub2 = new Intent(this, SubCategory.class);
                this.startActivity(sub2);
                break;
        }
    }
}
```

This is my Activity b

```
public class SubCategory extends AppCompatActivity {

private ListView listView;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_sub_category);

    listView = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.listview);
}
```

}

Comment: The code you post is incomplete.

Comment: @AndyDeveloper Tell me what's wrong... I'll correct it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Modify your both activities like this. It will work as per your need.

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements View.OnClickListener {

    private TextView a, b;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        a = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.a);
        b = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.b);

        a.setOnClickListener(this);
        b.setOnClickListener(this);
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        switch (v.getId()){
            case R.id.a:
                Intent sub1 = new Intent(this, SubCategory.class);
                sub1.putExtra("BUTTON_CLICKED", "A");
                this.startActivity(sub1);
                break;
            case R.id.b:
                Intent sub2 = new Intent(this, SubCategory.class);
                sub2.putExtra("BUTTON_CLICKED", "B");
                this.startActivity(sub2);
                break;
        }
    }
}
```

And:

```
public class SubCategory extends AppCompatActivity {

    private ListView listView;
    String buttonType;
    ArrayAdapter adapter;

    static final String[] FRUITS = new String[] { "Apple", "Avocado", "Banana"};
    static final String[] NAMES = new String[] { "Sachin", "Brett", "Shane", "Zaheer"};

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_sub_category);



        Bundle bundle = getIntent().getExtras();
        if(bundle != null) {
            buttonType = bundle.getString("BUTTON_CLICKED");
        }
        if(buttonType != null && buttonType.equals("A")) {
            adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, R.layout.activity_listview, FRUITS);
        } else if(buttonType != null && buttonType.equals("B")) {
            adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, R.layout.activity_listview, NAMES);
        }
        listView = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.listview);
        listView.setAdapter(adapter);
    }
}
```

Comment: i didn't get this "R.layout.activity_listview" from where you are taking  this layout "activity_listview"?

Comment: it is a simple xml contains only a Textview. Here I am pasting the code of xml in inverted commas "<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!--  Single List Item Design -->

<TextView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
          android:id="@+id/label"
          android:layout_width="fill_parent"
          android:layout_height="fill_parent"
          android:padding="10dip"
          android:textSize="16dip"
          android:textStyle="bold" >
</TextView>"

Comment: okay! thank you for the information, and i would like to ask only one last thing... later if i would like to make this listview items clickable... like if i want to add onclicklistner on this listview items inside subcategory... would it be possible using this method?

Comment: yes, use listView.setOnItemClickListener(). google for a sample of list item click

Answer (score 0):

You need to put extras into intent.

```
sub.putExtra("emp-type","EMPLOYEE TYPE HERE");
```

And in the new activity

```
 String empType = getIntent().getStringExtra("emp-type","");
```